# How to reconfigure apache httpd.conf file for local LAMP environment?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I was attempting to set-up my local environment for LAMP on my desktop with [Guy Nathan's Installing LAMP stack on OSX Mavericks with Homebrew updated guide](https://guynathan.com/install-lamp-stack-on-mavericks-with-homebrew-with-php-mcrypt).  Since I'm experienced with RoR, I proceeded with homebrews but along the way, evidently, I misconfigured the `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf` file because whenever I try to start the apache server with `sudo apachectl start` or test with `sudo apachectl configtest`, the following error is invariably returned:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 482 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf: No such file or directory
```

Due to the length of the 'http.conf' file, I've created a [gist of my 'httpd.conf file'](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/4e9b540f38e761e2faf2) for review.

At this point, I would just like to reset my 'httpd.conf' file, or whatever is necessary so I can properly configure my local environment for LAMP.  I've tried other solutions involving a reversion of `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update` but was unable to effect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing to start because the `httpd.conf` file is specifying an include of `/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf` which doesn't exist.

Either comment out line 482 by putting a `#` at the beginning of the line, or create an empty `/Sites/httpd-vhosts.conf` file so it can be included.  If its empty it won't have any effect.

Here are some [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) of what would typically go in that file.

Comment: @alexanderjsingleton Glad that was it!